# Getting "Could not find artifact org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:tests:4.3.5-local-SNAPSHOT" error while building Liquibase project on local

Tags: maven, liquibase

We are currently using liquibase version `4.3.5`.
We needed to update the spring version of the liquibase project for security reasons (Liquibase uses Spring version 5.0.12.RELEASE, which has some vulnerabilities ).

We did the following steps:

1. Clone liquibase repository from https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase
2. Checkout tag "v4.3.5" using command `git checkout v4.3.5`
3. Updated spring version in file "base.pom.xml" `<spring.version>5.3.0</spring.version>`
4. Ran command `mvn clean install  -DskipTests`. This command ran successfully
5. Ran command `mvn clean assembly:assembly -DskipTests`. This command failed with the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project liquibase-extension-examples: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.liquibase:liquibase-extension-examples:jar:4.3.5-local-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:tests:4.3.5-local-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :liquibase-extension-examples
```

Attaching screenshots for reference
[image: Spring Version Update Code]
[image: Error on building the project]

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a liquibase jar, run below command

```
mvn clean install  -DskipTests
```

This will create the jar in the following location:

```
liquibase-dist/target
```

[image: Jar Location]